# How can I apply custom colors to a PdfPCell's background?

Tags: css, pdf-generation, itext, rgb, background-color

I've got this iTextSharp code to give a cell on a PDF file a green background:

```
PdfPCell cellSec2 = new PdfPCell(parSectionHeading2);
cellSec2.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GREEN;
```

The problem is that "BaseColor.GREEN" is too dark/intense. I need more of a verdigris color - light green, or pale green. Is it possible to assign RGB (or RGBA) values or some such to the BackgroundColor property?

### UPDATE

Bruno's answer plus [this site](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm), and you've got what you need. I needed:

```
var lightGreen = new BaseColor(204, 255, 204);
cellSec2.BackgroundColor = lightGreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have plenty of documentation on all things iText. For instance: chapter 10 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book) is about images and color. If you don't own a copy of the book, why don't you take a look at the [examples of chapter 10](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C10)?

Take for instance [DeviceColor.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter10/DeviceColor.cs) where you have plenty of examples of other colors such as:

```
new GrayColor(0x20) // Gray value
new BaseColor(0f, 1f, 1f) // RGB
new CMYKColor(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF) // CMYK
```

The values for R, G and B, or for C, M, Y and K, can either be floats between 0 and 1 or integers between 0 and 255.